# HowTo Create First Viewcontroller Button Click to Call Second Viewcontroller Method Using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to create first `viewcontroller` button click to call second viewcntroller method without any navigation. I mean need to stay first view controller but need to cal method only on second viewcontroller and print there some `NSLog`.

Comment: You need to explain your issue in more detail, also posting any code you have. By the sounds of it, the design / structure of your app has some issues. Calling functionality of a viewController thats not in use is quite odd. You most likely want a third class with this functionality to share between the two viewControllers

Answer (score 2):

Simply try this:

**Second View Controller :**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doClickIt:) name:@"notificationName" object:nil];
}

-(void)doClickIt:(NSNotification*)notification {
}
```

**First View Controller:**

On Button click IBAction method called:

```
-(IBAction) someMethod3:(id) sender{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notificationName" object:obj];
}
```

Thats it.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: This actually wouldn't work because viewDidLoad is called once navigation begins. Also, using notifications seems really heavy for just calling a method on a view controller

Comment: @shabbirv ok than you can add observer in delegate & call method & from delegate you can call method of any view controller

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right you could do the following:

In your firstviewcontroller:

```
#import "secondviewcontroller.h" - (Or the name of the viewcontroller)
```

In the (IBAction) method do the following:

```
Secondviewcontroller *sec = [Secondviewcontroller alloc]init]
[sec theMethod];
```

Then it will get called.

Can i ask, how come you want to call an action from a non-active viewcontroller?

Comment: No visible @interface for secondviewcontroller declares the selector 'theMethod'@Jakob Mikkelsen

Comment: Its working but after entered inside method not calling another method!@Jakob Mikkelsen

Comment: Of course it has to be inside a method, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try Following:

In `ViewControllerA.h` declare a method.

In `ViewControllerA.m` Define a method.
like below:

```
-(NSMutableArray*) MethodOfA;
```

In `ViewControllerB.h`:

```
#import "ViewControllerA.h"
  .......
 @property (nonatomic, strong) ViewControllerA * viewControllerA;
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray * mutableArray;
```

In `ViewControllerB.m`:

in your Button action add below code:

```
self.mutableArray =[self.viewControllerA MethodOfA];
```